# Get TextBox Text into TCHAR* buffer

Tags: visual-c++

I'm new to Win Forms programming and have tried every possible way of doing this to no avail. My issue is getting the contents of a textbox into a WCHAR * buffer, as follows:

```
String^ strTemp = tbSrc->Text; // tbSrc is a simple textbox
TCHAR* tszTemp = new TCHAR[strTemp->Length + 1]; // Allocate TCHAR buffer
strTemp->CopyTo(0, tszTemp, 0, strTemp->Length); 
// **Won't compile as tszTemp is not an array type**
tszTemp[strTemp->Length] = NULL;
...
```

This example obviously doesn't work. I've inserted CopyTo to illustrate my problem. I'm not sure how to solve this. Could someone please offer some help. It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: TCHAR stopped making sense a decade ago, use char or wchar_t or a C++ string type like std::wstring.  You can't use String::CopyTo(), it requires a managed array.  Very different from a C array.  Check [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384865.aspx) to get ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're compiling a UNICODE project (i.e. `TCHAR` is `wchar_t`), you can do something like this

```
String^ strTemp = tbSrc->Text; // tbSrc is a simple textbox

// use marshalling to get wchar_t
IntPtr pString = Marshal::StringToCoTaskMemAuto(strTemp);
wchar_t *szWideChar = (wchar_t*)pString.ToPointer();

// ... do what you want with szWideChar here ...

// free the marshalled object
Marshal::FreeHGlobal(pString);
```